# how to add webview in Scrollable tabs?

Tags: android, webview

Can anyone tell how to add webview in scrollable tabs?

> MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */


    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
          switch (position)
          {
              case 0:
                  tab1contacts tab1=new tab1contacts();
                  return  tab1;
              case 1:
                  tab2chat tab2 =new tab2chat();
                  return  tab2;
              case 2:
                  tab3online tab3=new tab3online();
                  return  tab3;
                  default:
                      return null;
          }

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position)
            {
                case 0:
                    return "Contacts";
                case 1:
                    return "Chat";
                case 2:
                    return "Online";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

> Tab1

```
package com.example.nikhilarora.tabactu;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;

/**
 * Created by nikhil arora on 4/30/2018.
 */

public class tab1contacts extends Fragment{
    WebView webView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1contacts, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

> Tab2

```
package com.example.nikhilarora.tabactu;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

/**
 * Created by nikhil arora on 4/30/2018.
 */

public class tab2chat extends Fragment{
    WebView webView;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2chat, container, false);
        return  rootView;
    }}
```

I know how to add Webview in normal Activity but when I am applying the same logic in Tab1.java and Tab2.java it's not working anymore. Code that I wrote was:setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) String url="https://www.google.com/ webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.WebView);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); webView.loadUrl(url);

Comment: I think the simplest way is to disable a tab scrolling on that tab because in another way the scrolling can be unexpected for the user.

Comment: I have written the simplest way but I also think it's a right way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your webview into the corresponding layout files, in your case it will be `R.layout.tab1contacts` or `R.layout.tab2chat`.

Get the identifier e.g. tab2chat: `webView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview)` and make your settings.

Comment: can you also tell how to override onBackPressed like this                              
 `public void onBackPressed() {
           if(webView.canGoBack())
        {
            webView.goBack();
        }
        else
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
        } `                     in fragements.Is there any alternative to this? for tab-1 activity?

Comment: Notice device back press is managed through activities. Create a `public interface OnBackListener { void onBackPressed(); }`;
Define a `private OnBackListener onBackListener` and create a setter method also override `onBackPressed` in your `MainActivity`; Implement into your Fragment `... implements OnBackListener`, override `onCreateView` and put `((MainActivity)getActivity()).setOnBackListener(this)`, notice get fragment manager must be related to calling activity. Put your above code into the overriden listener method.